# WordPress in AWS Lightsail - restrict public IP

Tags: apache, ip

I have WordPress instance in AWS Lightsail with static public IP. I also created DNS record with domain to redirect to that IP.

How can I hide/restrict public IP? Meaning I can now go to just that IP but I don't want public to be able do it, only to domain. I have cert installed for domain but not for IP.

user goes to -> https://www.hello.com/ (1.1.1.1) - ALLOW

user goes to -> http://1.1.1.1/ - restrict

Comment: Check this: https://serverfault.com/questions/607137/restrict-direct-ip-access-to-website

Comment: I expect you can do that with Apache's VirtualHost. You probably want to set up a virtual host with the domain name (with and without www) for WordPress and have the default whatever you'd like to see for 1.1.1.1.